# How to pass comma in string via rHadoopClient?

Tags: r, hadoop, hive

I would like to read in a table stored in Hive into R and want to remove all commas in the process (to ensure that my columns are not messed up). I have the following command

```
rHadoopClient::read.hive( "select regexp_replace( a_column, ',', '$$$' ), regexp_replace( b_column, ',', '$$$' )  from a_table" )
```

I get the following error:

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:63 cannot recognize input near ',' ',' '35671' in select expression
>   Error in read.table( file=file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, :
>
> no lines available in input

The result of the rHadoopClient::read.hive function is a comma-separated table, so it's essential I change the commas in the query.

**Update:** switching the single and double quotes solved the problem.

Comment: Try using single quotes on the outside?

Comment: If you have a commas separated table, how would a column contain commas?

Comment: The original is not comma separated, the result from the read.hive function is.

Comment: Switching quotes did the trick, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the commas. How would you select multiple columns otherwise?

The problem is the quotes.

Use singular quotes on the outside and double quotes on the inside.